# Is it possible to hide the scroll bar on an HTML textarea element?

Tags: html, textarea, scrollbar

Is it possible to hide the scroll bar on an HTML textarea element using CSS or any other means ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
style="overflow:hidden"
```

Not sure why you'd want to do that, though.

Comment: Thanks. The reason is that I need to display some text using javascript in an element that has a "value" attribute and can be multi-line.

Comment: you could also use a pre or blockquote element

Comment: You *should* use a different element. Form controls are used to accept use input, not display output. Pick an element with the correct semantics.

Comment: Is it possible to hide it, but still be able to scroll?