# Make input element (type="text") handle multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter, input

I've created a form with an input, but the box only handles text in a single row. I would like to style it so that the input field is similar to that of Twitter's, where the box itself is multiple rows:

[image: twitter-input]

And it also expands when you hit enter:

[image]

This is currently what I have:

```
<form name="userForm">
  <input type="text" id="userInput" name="userInput" placeholder="Enter text here.">
  <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I've styled the button and the input, but haven't done anything to change its shape, so it's at default. What do I have to tweak to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use an HTML `<textarea>` element.

*From MDN:*

> [**`<textarea>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)
>
> The HTML `<textarea>` element represents a multi-line plain-text
>   editing control.

Using `<input>` for multiline text is not possible natively and, if hacked, would be invalid HTML.

*HTML5 spec:*

> [**4.10.5.1.2 Text (`type=text`) state and Search state
>   (`type=search`)**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#text-(type=text)-state-and-search-state-(type=search))
>
> The `input` element represents a ***one line*** plain text edit
>   control for the element's value.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

---

**Twitter input box**

You mention you want the textarea to resemble Twitter's (auto-resize / no scrollbar). Consider this option and the following SO posts:

> [**Autosize**](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)
>
> A small, stand-alone script to automatically adjust textarea height.

- [Is it possible to hide the scroll bar on an HTML textarea element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330895/3597276)
- [Remove scrollbars from textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19424887/3597276)
- [It is possible to expand a textarea only with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15865982/3597276)
- [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/454202/3597276)
- [is there a way to get a textarea to stretch to fit its content without using php or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2803880/3597276)

Answer (score 5):

Use TextArea.Alter rows and columns attribute according to requirement.

```
<textarea class="input" rows="10" cols="10">Some text here</textarea>
```

To add the hover effect and change the box size , use css. Assign a normal height and width, and change that on focus.

```
.input:focus {
    height:300px;
}
.input{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<div contenteditable="true">` ([supported well](https://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable)) with storing to `<input type="hidden">`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="multilineinput" contenteditable="true"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="detailsfield" name="detailsfield">
```

**js (using jQuery):**

```
$("#multilineinput").on('keyup',function(e) {   
    $("#detailsfield").val($(this).text()); //store content to input[type=hidden]
});
```

if anyone wanted to use this for wrapping a single line and using enter to submit or move on in the form, here is what to add:

```
$("#multilineinput").on('keypress',function(e) {    
    if(e.which == 13) { //on enter
        e.preventDefault(); //disallow newlines     
        // here comes your code to submit
    }
});
```