# TextArea fill remaining height in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains a label, a textarea and a button:

```
 <div style="height: 300px;">
   <label>Label</label
   <textarea/>
   <input type="button" value="Save"/>
 </div>
```

and what for the textarea to fill the remaining div.

How can the textarea fill the remaining height without calculating it. If I give height: 100% it gives the textarea a height that is outside the 300px;

EDIT:
I have changed from textbox to textarea as some comments suggested.

Also what I want are the 3 controls to be in a stack one below the other.

Comment: By textbox you mean the text input ?

Comment: rewrite your code it is somewhat ambigious

Comment: go through calc property of css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A text input can only be [single line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35542287/3597276). Unless you're talking about huge font size, I presume you mean a textarea, which allows multiline text input.

With a flex container, the children will automatically expand to cover the full height of the parent (`align-items: stretch` default). If you want to disable this full-height feature, you can override it where necessary (as I did on your button).

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

textarea {
  flex: 1; /* consume available width */
}

input {
  align-self: flex-start; /* override flex full-height columns feature */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea>textbox full height of parent</textarea>
  <input type="button" value="button">
</div>
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine.

Comment: The button seems to be next to the input, instead of below

Comment: That's correct, because that's the way you had it set up in your question. Simply add `flex-direction: column` to the `div`, and the items will stack vertically.