# Expand textarea to 100% height of parent in Chrome fails

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to expand textarea to 100% height of parent.

My code of setting text area "height: 100%;" works in Firefox, IE, but failed in Chrome. like:

[image]

Note the parent div height dynamically fills the remaining height space:

JSfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/tling/9z25z425/1/

Problem at this line:

```
<textarea placeholder="textarea won't fill 100% height" style="width: 100%;  height: 100%;  "></textarea>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978311/textarea-fill-remaining-height-in-a-div/42978540#42978540

Comment: For Chrome / Safari, the parent of `textarea` must have a defined height. Not the case in your code.

Comment: If you add `height: 100%` to the `textarea`'s parent div, it works. See the duplicate for other options.